# Generating strings and running out of memory

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, performance, permutation

I trying to generate random strings based on a certain length.  For example, if length = 4, I generate all strings from aaaa to zzzz.  I need all of the repeats for testing purposes later.  This is how I'm going about it:

```
len = 5
str = ('a'..'z').to_a.repeated_permutation(len).map(&:join)
```

The problem is that is takes up a lot of memory.  So much in fact, my program terminates due to the ruby interpreter no able to allocate enough memory.  Is there a less memory intensive way to generate these strings?

EDIT: Len is technically a variable.  It can range from 2 to 7.

Comment: While this actually works fine for me, it's an incredibly inefficient way to generate the 456976 possible strings. You're first building 456976 arrays of characters and then mapping every one through a `join`. You're going to be using orders of magnitude more memory and CPU than is required.

Comment: I read your length as 4 the first time. For 5 characters, you're looking at 11881376 strings, but first 11881376 5-element arrays being generated and joined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `('aaaaa'..'zzzzz').to_a`. It avoids the intermediate step of building out each number as an array of four letters, and joining them back into a string.

This is (on my system) on the order of four times faster, and it will almost certainly use a fraction of the memory.

> ... the problem is that len is a variable .... from 2 to 7

Then use `(('a' * len)..('z' * len)).to_a`. This is still faster, as the only temporary allocation is the strings generated by `'a' * len` and `'z' * len` which is between 4 and 14 characters.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my example, but the problem is len is a variable.  Len can range from 2 to 7.

Comment: So? Use `('a' * len)..('z' * len)` instead then.

Answer (score 0):

You can step through permutations one by one - depends if you need to process them in bulk later on.

So if you can feed strings into test one-by-one, then you can just do

```
enumerator = str = ('a'..'z').to_a.repeated_permutation(len)
my_test( enumerator )
```

And . . .

```
def my_test e
  e.each do |string|
  # Test it
end
```

That's still a lot to process though, I'd expect such code to take a few minutes at least to run, you are testing over 11 million separate strings.

Comment: You can *still* just use `'aaaa'..'zzzz'`. The real issue here is the use of repeated_permutation.

Comment: Yes, just tried that in IRB, and str = ('aaaaa'..'zzzzz').to_a is surprisingly fast.

Answer (score 0):

Lowering the amount of memory used could be acommplished by using the [flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) pattern.

I'm not sure how much time you are looking to invest in a solution but creating a class that has `x` many "letters" in it which are in a particular order and having each letter point to a shared pool of `String`s (one for each letter in the alphabet) would allow you to lower your memory (you could use a hash for this). You could then override the `to_s` for outputting your new object as well as modifying your `repeated_permutation` method to accept your new object.

Note that solution is only worth your time if you are expecting `len` to become quite large.

Comment: This could be accomplished by using symbols instead of strings for the individual characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
len = 5
(('a'*len)..('z'*len)).to_a
```